# How to stick relative element after fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image.png" class="child"/>
</div>
<div class="container">Page goes here.</div>
```

And the following css:

```
.container, .parent{
    position: relative;
}
.child{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Because the image is `fixed` the parent's height is probably 0. Therefore the container is placed over the image. However I want to have the image fixed and the container to be placed after the image, while keeping it responsive.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I'm trying to get the scrolling behavior shown in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8spngqz/1/), but to make the `container` always be at the bottom of the image, even if the screen width is (let's say) under `300px`.

Comment: just curious why does the image need to be in a fixed position? Looking at the fiddle I cannot think of a practical use for this. I would think using a css `background-image` would be better to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fiddle, I was able to achieve the desired behavior by changing the .container property from

`margin-top: 300px` to `margin-top:50%`

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely not see a change if you add a position class to the image. That's used on div tags. Try adding that class to a new div tag with which you surround your image.

Alternatively, you could add a display: block to your image, but that makes things more complicated.

I *think* this is what you're asking, but I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: You may also try setting both divs to "position: relative", which will force the other div underneath the other.

Comment: I've updated the post, trying to explain  better what I want.